# Place Checkboxes next to each other dynamically Android

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I want to place Check-boxes next to each other dynamically in android and when the width is over then the check boxes need to be aligned from the next line.

I have number of check-boxes which are initializing in an array. I have used the following code. It correctly place only one check-box. Other one gets placed in between. I have used the following code.

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_symptoms_checkboxes);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
    params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySymptoms.length; i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb.setText(arraySymptoms[i]);
        cb.setId(i);
        if(i==0)
        {
            cb.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(cb);
        }
        else
        {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, i-1);
            cb.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(cb);
        }

    }
```

Please guide me through this. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :D You take care. Have great day :)

Comment: Hi, Sorry to be a pain to you. I made the change and it worked but when the list is long. the last parts of the strings of array doesnt show up.

I have edited my code above for the current verion.

Comment: Hi again,

I sorted that out also using vertical orientation and using a scroll view.

Thank you anyway :)